# How to fix Warning: foreach() argument must be of type array|object, when using WordPress get_the_terms()?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, taxonomy-terms

I am using the code for displaying the most complete product tags on the category page from *[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64171548/woocommerce-turning-the-product-tag-cloud-into-a-complex-refine-feature)*.

The code displays the product tags dynamically with refinements for selection, but an error appears in the line `foreach ($tags as $tag)`: 
*"Warning: foreach() argument must be of type array|object, bool."*

I don’t understand what exactly I need to fix and how to fix this warning. Any help will be appreciated.

Here is the code that I am using:

```
function custom_product_tag_cloud_func() {
   if (is_shop()) {
       $args= array(
     'smallest' => 13,
     'largest' => 13,
     'taxonomy' => 'product_tag',
     'unit' => 'px',
     'number' => 10,
     'format' => 'flat',
     'separator' => " ",
     'orderby' => 'count',
     'order' => 'DESC',
     'show_count' => 0,
     'number' => 0,
       );
       echo'<div class="widget_product_tag_cloud"><span class="gamma widget-title"></span><div class="tagcloud"><ul class="wp-tag-cloud">';
       wp_tag_cloud($args);
       echo '</ul></div></div>';
   }
    global $wp;
    $current_slug = add_query_arg( array(), $wp->request );
    if(strpos($current_slug, '/') !== false) {
        $newtest = explode('/', $current_slug);
        $current_slug = array_pop($newtest);
    } 
    $args = array(
        'category' => array( $current_slug ),
        'limit' => -1,
    );
    $products = wc_get_products( $args );
    $tags_objects = array();
    foreach ($products as $product) {
        $tags = get_the_terms( $product->get_id(), 'product_tag' );
        foreach ($tags as $tag) { 
            $slug = $tag->slug;
            $cat_slug = add_query_arg( array(), $wp->request );
            $tag->link = get_term_link( $tag ); //get_site_url()."/".$cat_slug."?product_tag=".$slug;
            array_push($tags_objects,$tag);
        }
    }
    $tags_objects = array_unique($tags_objects, SORT_REGULAR);
    $args = array(
        'smallest' => 13,
        'largest' => 13,
           'number' => 10,
        'format' => 'flat',
        'separator' => " ",
        'orderby' => 'count',
        'order' => 'DESC',
        'unit' => 'px',
        'show_count' => 0,
        'number' => 0,
    );
    $tag_cloud = wp_generate_tag_cloud($tags_objects,$args);
    if(is_product_category()){
        echo'<div class="widget_product_tag_cloud"><span class="gamma widget-title"></span><div class="tagcloud"><ul class="wp-tag-cloud">';
        echo $tag_cloud;
        echo '</ul></div></div>';
    }
}
```

Comment: You have to check that `$tags` is actually an array (or object) before attempting to loop through it. Do you understand the basic premise of the error message? (If not, you can easily google it to get explanations). What debugging have you done? `var_dump($tags);` before the `foreach` would be a good start. Presumably it doesn't contain an array. Once you see what it does contain, you can trace back and debug to try and work out why.

Comment: We can see it's populated from the result of get_the_terms, which the [documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_terms/) says it can return `false` (which obviously isn't an array!) when there are no terms found. So if I had to guess (which I do, because you didn't provide any debugging data) I'd say that's the most likely reason for the problem.

Comment: Maybe related: [Display Custom Taxonomy in three columns, starting with first children](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32512551/2943403)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code, **for a `foreach` loop,** it is better to replace `get_the_terms()` with `wp_get_post_terms()`, as if there are no terms found, `wp_get_post_terms()` returns an empty array, which is not the case for `get_the_terms()` that returns `false` and throws that warning message.

Also, your current code can be lightened and optimized. Try the following:

```php
function custom_product_tag_cloud_func() {
    if ( is_shop() ) {
        echo'<div class="widget_product_tag_cloud"><span class="gamma widget-title"></span><div class="tagcloud"><ul class="wp-tag-cloud">';
        
        wp_tag_cloud( array(
            'smallest' => 13,
            'largest' => 13,
            'taxonomy' => 'product_tag',
            'unit' => 'px',
            'number' => 10,
            'format' => 'flat',
            'separator' => " ",
            'orderby' => 'count',
            'order' => 'DESC',
            'show_count' => 0,
            'number' => 0,
        ) );

        echo '</ul></div></div>';
    } 
    elseif ( is_product_category() ) {
        global $wp;

        $current_slug = add_query_arg( array(), $wp->request );

        if(strpos($current_slug, '/') !== false) {
            $newtest = explode('/', $current_slug);
            $current_slug = array_pop($newtest);
        } 
    
        $product_ids = wc_get_products( array(
            'status'   => 'publish',
            'category' => array( $current_slug ),
            'limit'    => -1,
            'return'   => 'ids', // return only product Ids
        ) );
    
        $tags_objects = array();
    
        foreach ($product_ids as $product_id) {
            $tags = wp_get_post_terms( $product_id, 'product_tag' );
    
            if ( ! empty( $tags ) && ! is_wp_error( $tags ) ) {
                foreach ( $tags as $tag ) { 
                    $slug = $tag->slug;
                    $cat_slug = add_query_arg( array(), $wp->request );
                    $tag->link = get_term_link( $tag );
                    array_push($tags_objects, $tag);
                }
            }
        }
    
        if( ! empty($tags_objects) ){
            $tags_objects = array_unique($tags_objects, SORT_REGULAR);
    
            echo'<div class="widget_product_tag_cloud"><span class="gamma widget-title"></span><div class="tagcloud"><ul class="wp-tag-cloud">';

            echo wp_generate_tag_cloud($tags_objects, array(
                'smallest' => 13,
                'largest' => 13,
                'number' => 10,
                'format' => 'flat',
                'separator' => " ",
                'orderby' => 'count',
                'order' => 'DESC',
                'unit' => 'px',
                'show_count' => 0,
                'number' => 0,
            ) );

            echo '</ul></div></div>';
        }
    }
}
```

It should not throw anymore this warning message.

Answer (score 2):

WordPress is written in PHP, a polymorphic language, which is common knowledge. The negative (or fail) return is often a boolean or a WP_Error. Check the official documentation for function returns. Therefore, you need to validate your data before executing your loop.

It's good practice to always validate data before executing any code.